# how to retrieve text file inside assets folder and pass to ffmpeg command flutter

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg

I have created mylist.txt file inside assets folder.
Now I want to pass this text file to ffmpeg command working with flutter.
This is my code.

```
String commandToExecute =
      'ffmpeg -framerate 2 '
      '-f concat -i mylist.txt -i ${AUDIO_PATH} -s 1080x1620 -y ${OUTPUT_PATH}';
```

This is my mylist.txt file

```
file '/storage/emulated/0/Download/000.jpeg'
file '/storage/emulated/0/Download/001.jpeg'
file '/storage/emulated/0/Download/002.jpeg'
file '/storage/emulated/0/Download/003.jpeg'
```

please help me

Comment: You can't pass assets files in ffmpeg instead download assets into memory then use them

Comment: I download by using this code String myString = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/mylist.txt'); please tell me how to pass to ffmpeg command

Comment: I have list of image like List<String> pic= {a.jpeg,1jpeg,abcjpeg} in flutter code. Can I pass this list direct to ffmpeg like ffmpeg.execute(-i pic -y song.mp4)

Comment: String commandToExecute = ' -framerate 1/4.5 -i "$img1" -i "$img2" -i "$img3" -filter_complex "concat=n=3:v=0:a=0" -f mp3 -i ${AUDIO_PATH} -s 1080x1620 -y ${OUTPUT_PATH}'; i have this commend but when video generated it only show 1 image in video not other 2

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to context, you can use:

```
String myString = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/mylist.txt');
```

To get strings from your asset.

Don't forget to declare asset in `pubspec.yaml` :

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/mylist.txt
```

Comment: String myString = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/mylist.txt'); This returns whole file in string form and when I pass myString to ffmpeg as an input it gives error.

Comment: here is my code String commandToExecute =
          '-framerate 2 '
           ' -i "$myString" -s 1080x1620 -y ${OUTPUT_PATH}'; but it convert whole mylist.txt file into string

Comment: You have to process text file content and pass it to ffmpeg

Comment: How ? Please provide some code

Comment: I have list of image like List<String> pic= {a.jpeg,1jpeg,abcjpeg} in flutter code. Can I pass this list direct to ffmpeg like ffmpeg.execute(-i pic -y song.mp4)

Comment: String commandToExecute =
          ' -framerate 1/4.5 -i "$img1" -i "$img2" -i "$img3" -filter_complex "concat=n=3:v=0:a=0" -f mp3 -i ${AUDIO_PATH} -s 1080x1620 -y ${OUTPUT_PATH}'; i have this commend but when video generated it only show 1 image in video not other 2

Comment: Parse the list to create a string you can concatene in your ffmeg comand string.

Comment: give example with code please